# Upload image file from directory to websites

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, directory

I'm trying to upload image files (e.g. .jpg .jpeg .png) to certain social media websites (i.e. twitter) using the Tor Browser yet the uploaded images look all jumbled up, as in, there are pixels but the image is rendered as an unrecognizable pattern of different colors. Any idea what's causing this? OR what's the right way to upload an image to these web services? Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: what is a canvas

Comment: @user610620: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API

Comment: @Steve `privacy.resistFingerprinting` worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter is probably using the [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) to manipulate the photo. There are several other posts about Twitter photo uploads not working due to the canvas, but last year Tor Browser changed the canvas extraction to return a pattern of random colors, which is probably the new behaviour you're seeing. You can try temporarily disabling the `privacy.resistFingerprinting` option in your `about:config` settings, and then re-enabling it after you're done.