# Changing twitter profile picture in tor results in broken / static like image

Tags: settings

I am trying to upload new profile picture to twitter using tor (image has all exif data deleted), however once I upload image that twitter displays is broken, it basically just shows colourful vertical lines, kinda like old tv static.

I assume this is due to some setting in Tor not allowing this? Is it possible to bypass it and upload an image?

Comment: See https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/21982/24966

Comment: I agree with Steve. Also, there have been many posts on this site about how Twitter doesn't properly work with Tor, so I also suggest checking that out and anything else related to the topic.